# Port forwarding: Modem -> Router -> AP -> Server

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, mikrotik-routeros

Attached is my network diagram. I have a Modem -> Router -> AP -> Server setup and want to forward port 443 through them. I have tried 3 configurations in the IP > Firewall > NAT but isn't able to get it to work. I have a domain sub.example.com with A record to 67.149.141.59. The goal is to have sub.example.com connect to the "Server" (in the diagram). How do I set this up correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: network diagram]
[image: RouterOS IP address]

[image: Google Wi-Fi "WAN" IP address]
[image: Google Wi-Fi "LAN" IP address]
[image: Google Wi-Fi DHCP reservations]
[image: Google Wi-Fi port forwarding rules]

Comment: Could you update the diagram to include *all* addresses that the Mikrotik router has? It's a router – it doesn't make any sense for it to have only one address, and in this case it would be important to know what IP address it has on the "WAN" port, not just the LAN side. (Same goes for the Google AP which is a router too, and its both addresses should be in the diagram.)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand the request. The WAN IP is 67.149.141.59 is already included on the diagram. Only the "Google WiFi AP" is connected to the Mikrotik Router on the LAN side. All other LAN devices (including the server) connect wirelessly to the "Google WiFi AP". The Mikrotik Router is wired only (not wireless) and only used for its RouterOS software (default configuration except this firewall rule for port forwarding).

Comment: It's in the diagram on the modem. I was talking about the Mikrotik router. If it's really a router, then it belongs to at least two networks and will have at least two IP addresses (one from each network), since that's what a router does. So either the diagram has 67.149.141.59 on the wrong device, or there are more addresses that the diagram is missing. Could you check the router's "IP → Addresses" section (or `/ip address print`)?

Comment: Got it, here's a screenshot of that section: https://imgur.com/a/ehfeev2

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. Could you also find the same for the Google WiFi device? Your diagram shows it as having its own subnet and doing port-forwarding, which means it's in fact a router and has to have an address from the 192.168.88.x range in addition to the 192.168.86.1 one. I *think* the app should show it (possibly labelled "WAN address", even if isn't one) but in any case it should also show up somewhere in Mikrotik's "DHCP Server → Leases".

Comment: Here's few relevant screenshots of the WAN address (matches the one in Mikrotik's "DHCP Server → Leases"), DHCP assigned IP to server, port forwarding, etc. https://imgur.com/a/Hnu4Dkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a more accurate diagram for your network would look like this:

[image: The diagram]

Generally, a router always belongs to at least two networks and will have addresses from each network. (On the other hand, a plain AP wouldn't create its own network – it would just bridge the same network on both sides. Unfortunately Google Wi-Fi appliances lose many features when switched to bridge mode.)

In your config attempts, you're misunderstanding what RouterOS means by "source" and "destination" addresses. Both parameters match different fields on the original packet information, and they are *not* the same thing as "original" and "new".

(This can be confusing because many other routers use the labels "from" & "to" in their port-forwarding setup screens, but they specifically mean "change from <old> to <new>" – they don't mean "send from <src> to <dst>".)

So your rule should look more like the following:

- Src Address: *not set* (match packets coming from any source)
- Dst Address: `67.149.141.59` (match packets sent to this destination)
- Protocol: `6 (tcp)`
- Dst Port: `443`
- Action: dst-nat
- To Address: `192.168.88.254` (set the Google WiFi AP/router as the new destination)
- To Port: `443`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry for the delay in response, I just had a chance to try out your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work, so to eliminate the Google Wifi AP/Router doing anything unexpected, I connected the Ubuntu server directly to the Mikrotik router and got an IP of `192.168.88.253`. I set that as the "To Address", still nothing. For debugging, I tried `0-65535` for Dst Port & To Ports, still nothing. When I try `http://192.168.88.253`, nginx loads, but `http(s)://67.149.141.59` times out. What am I overlooking? How to further debug?

Comment: If you're testing `https://67.149.141.59` from within inside your own LAN, search for articles about the "NAT hairpinning" problem. And if you're testing from outside, use Mikrotik's packet sniffer (under `/tool sniffer quick` via SSH) to verify that it is actually receiving the packets from the ISP on interface=ether1, and that it is forwarding them correctly NATed out through interface=bridge.

Comment: Also, don't forget that the inbound packets are still subject to the router's firewall rules – unlike most home routers, Mikrotik RouterOS _does not_ automatically add a forward allow rule corresponding to the dst-nat rule. You should make sure the connection is allowed in IP>Firewall>Filter (in the 'forward' chain).

Comment: For now, I'm trying `https://67.149.141.59` from outside the LAN to avoid NAT hairpinning problem. Will look into that after getting things to work. I added the following firewall rule: chain: `Forward`, Dst Address: `67.149.141.59`, Protocol: `6 (tcp)`, Dst. Port: `0-65535` Action: `accept`. Still nothing. How do I set that up?

Comment: At this point Dst Address is not 67.149.141.59 anymore, it's 192.168.88.253. Generally you have 'dst-nat', then routing, then the 'forward' rules, then 'src-nat'. Meaning that routing &c. are done against the NATed destination, not the original one. And as a side note this means you can have a firewall rule that specifically matches "dst-nat"ed packets, without necessarily having to specify a port or an address.

Comment: I tried 192.168.88.253 as the Dst Address, still nothing. I did more research and couldn't find anything useful. To ensure proper nginx setup on the server, I removed Mikrotik router and only used the Google Wifi Router/AP, then everything worked. What else is needed beside the NAT rule and Filter "forward" rule is needed to get port forwarding properly working with Mikrotik router? I have the Ubuntu server directly connected to the Mikrotik router and server has LAN IP: 192.168.88.253.

Comment: I added hairpin rule to NAT. The Src Address and Dst Address is `192.168.88.1/24`. The action is `masquerade`. Then it worked! user1686, I really appreciate all of your help and great explanations! I hope this answer helps someone else who runs into this issue.